# Datatables. Keeping selected row after submit

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have a Thymeleaf template with a Datatable (1.10.15)

```
<script th:inline="javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#deviceEventTable').dataTable( {
        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bStateSave": true,
        "pageLength": 20,
    }); 

    $('#deviceEventTable tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {        
        $(this).closest("tr").toggleClass('selected');
    });  

} );

</script>
```

I also have this defined in the Table

```
<tr th:each="deviceEvent : ${deviceEvents}"  onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('deviceEventFormId').submit();"    >
```

Would be possible to keep he selected row after submitting ?

Comment: Could create a hidden input to store the row? submitting that row from code to hidden input...maybe? Just thinking out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the [**`select`**](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/) extension? Makes it a lot easier to keep track of selected rows. Then you can store which rows is selected each time a selection or deselection is made :

```
table.on('select.dt deselect.dt', function() {
  localStorage.setItem( 'DataTables_selected', table.rows( { selected: true }).toArray() )   
})
```

Use the `initComplete` callback to restore the selected-state when the table is initialised :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  select: true,
  stateSave: true,
  initComplete: function() {
    var api = this.api();
    var selected = localStorage.getItem( 'DataTables_selected' ).split(',');
    selected.forEach(function(s) {
      api.row(s).select();
    })
  }
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/jrjfhjf9/**

Try to select some rows and click <kbd>run</kbd> (for reloading) or copy the URL to another browser tab.

Answer (score 1):

The same approach as @davidkonrad (previous answer), fixed the NULL/UNDEFINED value:
http://jsfiddle.net/hvx2n0qa/

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  select: true,
  stateSave: true,
  initComplete: function() {
    var api = this.api();
    
    if (localStorage.getItem( 'DataTables_selected' ) != undefined){
        var selected =  localStorage.getItem( 'DataTables_selected' ).split(',');
    selected.forEach(function(s) {
      api.row(s).select();
    })
    }

  }
})  

table.on('select.dt deselect.dt', function() {
  localStorage.setItem( 'DataTables_selected', table.rows( { selected: true }).toArray())   
})
```